# Made for TV movie about aliens on the moon impregnating earth women

Tags: story-identification, aliens

Made for TV movie from late 70s/early 80s in which women are impregnated by a laser beam sent by aliens who are on the moon. They are dying out and need to replace themselves and are using the Earth women to produce hybrid children to take back to their world.

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Specifically things like when you read it, or where? Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Impregnating earth women from the moon, now *that's* a long shot! #SorryNotSorry

Comment: Thats really? Hahaha amazing movie xd

Comment: The only 70s TV movie I can think with some of these features is "The Stranger Within".  I don't remember a laser.  [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0072219/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_37).  [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Stranger_Within).